# How to open a new window in browser with focus

Tags: c#, silverlight

I would like to know how to open new window in the browser with focus while keeping the other window open too.

I have a button in my silverlight app that must open a pdf in another window or tab, i want the new window to have focus while keeping the initial page open.

I can get the new window to open but without focus or i can get it to replace the current page , then returning to the app requires login etc.

So i need 3 things...
1)open new window 
2)focus new window 
3)leave old window open

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(@"http://......./ViewPDF.aspx");
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri, "_newWindow");

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri);
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("window.focs()")
HtmlPage.PopupWindow(myUri, "_blank", null);
```

None of these meet all 3 requirements.

please help..

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Did you try HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri, "_blank", null) instead of HtmlPage.PopupWindow?

Comment: Was trying it on an older browser, so that and perhaps browser settings play a role. its working now ..

Comment: Is it possible for you to use javascript in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlPopupWindowOptions options = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions();

```
        options.Left = 300;
        options.Top = 150;
        options.Width = 1024;
        options.Height = 768;
        options.Directories = false;
        options.Location = false;
        options.Menubar = false;
        options.Status = false;
        options.Toolbar = false;
```

Uri myUri = new Uri(@"http://......./ViewPDF.aspx");

HtmlPage.PopupWindow(Uri, "_blank", options);